# Applicative scanning arguments right to left

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have come across several situations where I would like to use applicative style `f <$> x1 <*> x2 <*> x3` but scanning the applicative arguments right to left instead of the usual left to right.

Naturally, if I bring this into a monadic context, I can do this without problem:

```
liftM3' :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m a3 -> m r
liftM3' f x1 x2 x3 = do { x3' <- x3; x2' <- x2; x1' <- x1; return f x1' x2' x3' }
```

So, for my question: **is there some general method to accomplish this in the context of only `Applicative` (perhaps a newtype wrapper) and if not, why can there not be one**. That said, any insight about elegant solutions or workarounds to this problem are welcome.

*Aside*: My solution had been to define new right associative operators, but the solution was by no means elegant.

*Edit*: Here is my solution (I'd be interested in knowing if there is something equivalent in the standard libraries), if I require `Monad`:

```
newtype Reverse m a = Reverse (m a)

instance Monad m => Functor (Reverse m) where
  f `fmap` x = pure f <*> x

instance Monad m => Applicative (Reverse m) where
  pure x = Reverse $ return x
  (Reverse f) <*> (Reverse x) = Reverse $ do { x' <- x; f' <- f; return $ f' x' }
```

Comment: You might be interested in the [`ApplicativeDo`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ApplicativeDo) proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Backwards`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html) type is like your `Reverse`, and in a semi-standard package.

Comment: `transformers` is quite standard enough for me. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, another quick followup, is there a nice easy way of reversing `Applicative`, `Foldable` and `Traversable` all at once? Maybe with `Compose`? I couldn't get the kinds to work...

Comment: @Alec `Reverse (Backwards f)`, I guess. Though it looks like you may have to add `deriving instance Foldable f => Foldable (Backwards f)` or similar (and for `Traversable`). I would bet upstream would accept a patch to add these instances.

Answer (score 0):

> Naturally, if I bring this into a monadic context, I can do this without problem:

Don't forget that `f` is just a function. As such, you can simply define another function that takes the arguments in another order and then fall back to the usual applicative combinators:

```
-- | Lifts the given function into an applicative context.
-- The applicative effects are handled from right-to-left
-- e.g. 
-- >>> liftA3 (\_ _ _ -> ()) (putStr "a") (putStr "b") (putStr "c")
-- will put "cba" on your console.
liftA3Rev :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f d
liftA3Rev f x y z = f' <$> z <*> y <*> x
  where
    f' = \c b a -> f a b c
```

It's probably either impossible, or quite hard to write this with operators only, though. This is due to the nature of partial application. Remember that for `f :: Int -> Char -> Bool` and `Applicative f => f Int`, the expression `f <$> x`
has type `Applicative f => f (Char -> Bool)`. We always "lose" types on the left end, not on the right end. If you change the order of arguments, it's easy again:

```
(>*>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f (a -> b) -> f b
(>*>) = flip (<*>)
infixr 4 >*> -- right associative

liftA3Rev' :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f d
liftA3Rev' f x y z = z >*> y >*> x >*> pure f
```